# UICollectionView scrolling is not smooth. Why?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Why my `UICollecionView`'s scrolling is not smooth?

This is the code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellRecipe";

// Configure the cell...

[cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgRecipeCell.png"]]];

cell.image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.image.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
cell.image.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
cell.image.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

Recipes *recipe = [recipesArray_ objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

//checking for purchase
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSObject *object = [prefs objectForKey:@"com.__.__.recipefree"];

if ([recipe.isPaid integerValue] == 0) {
    [cell.freeImage setHidden:NO];
}
else [cell.freeImage setHidden:YES];

if ([object isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]) {
    [cell.freeImage setHidden:YES];
}

if ([recipe.isFavorite integerValue] == 0) {
    [cell.favImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toFavorite.png"] ];
}
else [cell.favImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"toFavorite_.png"]];

[cell.recipeName setText: recipe.name];
[cell.image setImage:recipe.thumbImage];

MainTabController *mainTabController = [[MainTabController alloc] init];
int difficulty = [recipe.difficulty intValue];
//this is the function which return an image for difficulty level from 1 to 5
[cell.difficultyImage setImage: [mainTabController imageForRating:difficulty]];

return cell;
```

Comment: May be because of cell.image.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;. Try commenting the code and run once to confirm. Its better to have bgRecipeCell.png with rounded corners and also the borders.

Comment: Also make sure that the `png` files are not transparent (in the simulator you can do that by selecting Debug->Color Blended Layers). Alpha blending is an expensive operation, and if you can avoid that it should dramatically increase your performance.

Comment: @StatusReport: I have removed PNGs, but scrolling still not smooth ((

Comment: @Norbert: I think you are wright. I have commented these `cell.image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.image.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;` and scrolling become more smoothy

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the layer border was breaking the smoothness. As I really wanted the border to be there, and I could not use images (the background color must be changeable), I solved it with the following UIView hierarchy:

```
UIView with rounded corners coloured with "border colour"
    UIView with rounded corners coloured with "content colour"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but in case if anyone still looking for answer then a short trick will be, in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, first `dequeue` your `collectionView` cell :

`CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`

and then add the following line:

`cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
 cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;`