# Tab bar with slide out menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uitabbar, unwind-segue

[image: My Storyboard]

RearViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)unwindFromViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"unwindToViewController"]) {
      ViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:detail animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

If I click back from my `RearViewController` the `ViewController` is not presented instead it just peeps and goes off(again shows `RearViewcontroller`).

**Image2**

[image]

Comment: can you give us a screenshot of the app while running? this might help a little more to understand what you want to say

Comment: sorry I couldn't take the screenshot because ViewController disappears within 2 seconds

Comment: Then switch the iOS simulator to slow animation with CMD + T when simulator is selected, so you might be able to catch the screen in time

Comment: I had updated please check

Comment: I don't understand, there are to images, are these 2 different screens or where is the focus exactly?

Comment: In Image 2 you can see the RearviewController at top and ViewController in bottom

Comment: Do you want to set tab bar with slide in and out menu?

Comment: Yeah I need to set tab bar with slide in and out menu in home page.

Comment: Are you preferred tab bar using storyboard or XIB?But you use tab bar using storyboard as posted screenshot.

Comment: Using storyboard only..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84775/discussion-between-user3182143-and-pavithra-selvaraj).

Comment: @user3182143 How to scroll collectionView smoothly??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335176/uicollectionview-scrolling-is-not-smooth-why

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336772/uicollectionview-performance-updatevisiblecellsnow

Comment: I used those method it doesn't work for me

Comment: Does it scroll properly?

Comment: Yeah its slow in scrolling

Comment: Can you show me when you are scrolling?

Comment: can we have the discussion in chat

Comment: Yes.still when will you work?

Comment: Are you there pavithra?

Comment: can you create another chat room..

Comment: I have a doubt @user3182143 are you there?

Comment: Tell me what is your problem?

Comment: app getting crashed after a long days from xcode build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you a solution for your question.

```
      1.First remove triggered segue connection.
      2.After that give push segue connection to Back to your required view controller.
      3.Click Back Button Segue and give Identifier name as "goToMainViewController" or whatever you want just give there.Also segue should be "push".
```

Thank You